# Xcode: Why is my passing variable "(null)"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Scenario = There are three view controllers. The first two view controllers have a table view that allows the users to select a row of data and then it will segue to the third view controller which will display details about the row that they have selected. On the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, an "objectID" is set to a variable called "selectedObjectID" that needs to be passed to next view controller to query for the objectID. The key to this is to understand that **both** the first two view controllers use the other view controller to display the details.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    PFObject *objectID = [collectionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    selectedObjectID = [objectID objectId];

    NSLog(@"didSelectRowAtIndexPath = %@", selectedObjectID);

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"details" sender:self];

}


-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier  isEqual: @"details"]) {

        NSLog(@"prepareForSegue = %@", selectedObjectID);

        DetailsViewController *details = [segue destinationViewController];
        details.selectedObjectID = selectedObjectID;
    }
}
```

**NOTE**
The first of the view controllers works exactly the way it should. A user selects a row and the objectID is set and passed to the next view controller. Everything is perfect.

Problem = I am doing the exact same thing (and by exact I mean copy and paste) in the first VC as the second VC but the second is not passing the variable to the details view controller like the first.

I have placed NSLogs in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath and prepareForSegue methods of the first two view controllers and in the viewDidLoad of the details view controller. Please bear with me while I illustrate what it logs out to me.

LOG RESULTS AS FOLLOWS

**FIRST VIEW CONTROLLER**

```
didSelectRowAtIndexPath = Kv5rL3Usa6
prepareForSegue = Kv5rL3Usa6
viewDidLoad = Kv5rL3Usa6
```

**SECOND VIEW CONTROLLER**

```
prepareForSegue = (null)
viewDidLoad = (null)
didSelectRowAtIndexPath = Zz81bHEeJD
```

The didSelectRowAtIndexPath gets called last. How can that happen when you have to select the row to call the segue from the get go? This does not make any sense to me. Please help.

Comment: Is the segue in both cases connected from the ViewController to the DetailViewController or is connected to the UITableViewRow ? If it's connected to the row, the prepareForSegue is called before the performSegueWithIdentitfier in didSelectRow.

Comment: The segue goes from view controller to view controller. It does not originate from the tableViewCell.

Comment: Can you put break points in both view controllers in didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate method and try to select row in second view controller and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

i propose that you log the addresses of the involved objects.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    PFObject *objectID = [collectionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    selectedObjectID = [objectID objectId];

    NSLog(@"didSelectRowAtIndexPath = %@ (self=%@)", selectedObjectID, self);

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"details" sender:self];

    NSLog(@"still didSelectRowAtIndexPath. self=%@)", self);
}


-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier  isEqual: @"details"]) {

        NSLog(@"prepareForSegue = %@", selectedObjectID);

        DetailsViewController *details = [segue destinationViewController];
        details.selectedObjectID = selectedObjectID;

        NSLog(@"still prepareForSegue. self=%@; details=%@", self, details);
    }
}
```

and in `-viewDidLoad` also log `self` in the same way...

the `self` in `-viewDidLoad` should equal the `details` in prepareForSegue... I suspect here is the problem...

Comment: Just ran that. What is that supposed to do? What it logged was the same address (0x166ee6b0) for all except the first "still prepareForSegue" line.

Comment: What does knowing the address of the objects have to do with resolving the issue? I'm cornfused.

Comment: I suspected that you set the `selectedObjectId` on one object, and read it in another object... Either this, or you resetting it to nil somewhere...

Comment: selectedObectID is a property in the destination view controller (view controller #3). Never changes. The first two view controllers (view controller #1 and #2) set that property in the prepareForSegue. And both #1 and #2 do it with the exact same code, but yet produces different results. That equals confusion.

Comment: @TomTesticool you have to track down the places where you set the variable, and the places where you read it. And then you will probably see that the variables are different. (like details1.oid=SOMETHING, later use details2.oid and wonder it's still nil.)

Comment: I set the variable for the destination view controller in the prepareForSegue method. I read it in the destination view controller's viewDidLoad method. And it logs "(null)". I already figured that out.